# Nested material-ui table using recursive function on tree data structure, how to align columns?

Tags: reactjs, recursion, html-table, nested, material-ui

I have a nested material-ui, the code for which is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-table-with-recursive-function-803qt?file=/src/App.js) table which displays a to-do-list of tasks. I use a tree structure to store the tasks and their child tasks and so on. The problem I have is that the table's columns do not line up with each other or the header, I believe this is due to the div tags surrounding the tableRow and Collapse components and possibly the collapse component, however I'm not sure how to rewrite the code without this, as the function must render a row for the tasks data and run the function recursively on the tasks' children in the collapse component to render them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented a solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-table-with-recursive-function-aligned-l56h9?file=/src/App.js) that works pretty well.

The 2 problems were in this particular function for the table rows:

```
function treeTable(taskTree) {
    return taskTree.children.map(task => (
      <div>
        <TableRow hover key={task.value.id}>
          {headers.map(({ key, format = value => value }) => (
            <TableCell>{format(task.value[key])}</TableCell>
          ))}
          <TableCell padding="default">
            {task.children.length > 0 ? (
              <Button
                key={task.value.id}
                onClick={() => handleClick(task.value.id)}
              >
                {state[task.value.id] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
              </Button>
            ) : null}
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <Collapse
          key={task.value.id}
          // component="table"
          in={state[task.value.id]}
          timeout="auto"
          unmountOnExit
        >
          {treeTable(task)}
        </Collapse>
      </div>
    ));
  }
```

Problem 1: the  wrapping the table row and collapse element breaks the continuity of the table components (which must come one after the other without another component outside). The solution here was simple, to replace the div with a React.fragment.

Problem 2: The collapse component also breaks this continuity of table components. If one instead puts the contents of the cells in a collapse component then they collapse appropriately.

The other facet of this solution is it now means one must pass down the state key for the collapse element down into the function as an argument, with a parent key for the top layer which is created and set true on the first load of the react component, when that state is undefined.

In order to have the rows collapse one must also add the prop `style={{ padding: 0 }}` to any cells containing collapse components (if you want more padding when the rows are expanded you'll need to add a conditional padding.

The improved function is now as follows:

```
function treeTable(taskTree, collapseId) {
    return taskTree.children.map(task => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <TableRow hover key={task.value.id}>
        {headers.map(({ key, format = value => value }) => (
            <TableCell style={{ padding: 0 }}>
              <Collapse
                key={collapseId}
                // component="table"
                in={state[collapseId]}
                timeout="auto"
                unmountOnExit
              >
                {format(task.value[key])}
              </Collapse>
            </TableCell>
          ))}
          <TableCell style={{ padding: 0 }}>
            <Collapse
              key={collapseId}
              // component="table"
              in={state[collapseId]}
              timeout="auto"
              unmountOnExit
            >
              {task.children.length > 0 ? (
                <Button
                  key={task.value.id}
                  onClick={() => handleClick(task.value.id)}
                >
                  {state[task.value.id] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                </Button>
              ) : null}
            </Collapse>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        {treeTable(task, task.value.id)}
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
  }
```